# Manage access rights to WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

After `techdays` in `geneva`, I'm looking forward about `WCF Data Service`, and I've several questions. I've actually a sample demo which permits me to retrive data from my database.

It is working quite good and I'm surprised by the speed :).

I saw that I've to declare what we can read/modify:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

But In this WCF service I don't see anything about authentication, so here are my questions:

- How can I say who can access to my service, and with which authentication(Windows, custom, SSL cert, ...)
- How can I say that the user group A has the right to read my collection, and the user group B has the right to edit it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more granular control over authentication on your data, you need to authenticate your users with classic WCF authentication methods and use Query and Change Interceptors to control who can read or change your data.

More information about the Query and Change interceptors here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx

Thanks
Pablo.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I took a look at your link, but I don't see how adding a "[ChangeInterceptor("Products")]" can let met indicate which user group should access to theses products?